# If $H$ is non-abelian and $H \unlhd \langle H, K \rangle$, how is $[H,K] \unlhd H$?

Tags: group-theory

I can see that if $H \unlhd \langle H, K \rangle$, then $[H,K] \le H$, but I don't see how can it be normal.

Comment: You need to prove that $[h_1,k]^{h_2} \in [H,K]$ and that follows from commutator identity number 3 in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutator

Comment: Thanks so much. We get $[h_1, k]^{h_2} = [h_1 h_2, k][h_2, k]^{-1} \in [H, K]$.

Comment: More generally, we always have $[H,K] \unlhd \langle H,K \rangle$.